# Scroll Flutter's multi-line TextField to end

Tags: flutter

I have a periodic function which appends text to a TextField.
For this purpose I set a `TextEditingController` and invoke: `controller.text += someText`.

However, when the TextField is scrolled and text is added, the TextField automatically scrolls back to the top and the just appended text gets out of view.

Is there any way to change the scroll behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Set the selection using the `TextEditingController`.
This will prevent the `TextField` from rebuilding every time and/or moving the cursor to the start of the `TextField`.

```
   TextField(
    controller: textEditController,
    onChanged: (content) {
      textEditController..text = someText
                        ..selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset:  textEditController.text.length);
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can serve you already today but in case someone else sees the publication I hope that helps, I'll say that I do this with a `SingleChildScrollView()` and I set the reverse property to `true`. I have to say that I don't use a `TexField()`, you use a `Text()`, but it behaves well and every time the text increases a line automatically the reverse property of the `SingleChildScrollView()` causes it to scroll down and always see the last thing that is being written.

This is a small example of how I do it in my code:

```
 Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            height: size.height*0.044,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(reverse: true,child: Text(valorOperacion1, style: GoogleFonts.exo(color: tema.hintColor, fontSize: 18.0.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),))
          ),
```